# Scanning images from ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, scanning, twain, wia

I need to scan a document from my asp.net web application. I searched for some tools to integrate scanner to my web application. But I couldn't find any free tools. Is there any free plugins for scanning in asp.net or is there any other way we could achieve this. Please suggest

Comment: I had to do something like this several years ago.  At the time, I used a small Silverlight plugin that hit the windows APIs for the scanner.  I have also seen use of an ActiveX control to do similar things.  Both of these are now frowned on technologies though.

Comment: Yes,It seems Silverlight is not supported in chrome. So I couldn't prefer silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some controls like Imageman, that maybe will do it, but you can suffer limitations like "this only works on Internet explorer" due to Silverlight or COM dependency, or they are very expensive, like dynamsoft web twain....

And you say "free tools". More complex indeed.

You can consider develop a very simply .NET (o JAVA) app for scan. The users could download it from your web, scan the files, and the App send images to server vía REST or WCF service.

So .... maybe it would be better for you: allow users to attach files :)